# Php Loop with a List

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP code like that:

```
$cityCount=10;
$currentUsers = array();
$addedUsers = array();
for ($cityId = 1; $cityId <= $cityCount; $cityId++) {
    $currentUsers[$cityId] = array();
    $addedUsers[$cityId] = array();
}
```

However, I want to change the for and I want to define an array for cities because new city will be added and it'i city id will be 22(not 11. If it could be 11 there was going to be just one change at code $cityCount=11; but city id is not sequential now.)

As like:

```
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,22]
```

I want to iterate over that array.

Also I have a code like that:

```
for ($cityId = 1; $cityId <= $cityCount; $cityId++) {
    foreach ($addedUsers[$cityId] as $userId) {
        if($added) $addSql .= ",\n";
        $addSql .= '(' . $userId . ", " . $cityId . ')';
        $added++;
}
```

How to change this code according to new version of code?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I used to iterate over a for loop. My cities were 10 and their ids are 1,2,3,....,8,9,10. However my new city id will be 22. So I need a change on my code.

Comment: from where do you get your cities? what is your WHOLE task? are you getting it from database? it seems it's quite common task and you're doing it extremely wrong way. most likely you have to use no PHP at all but SQL only.

Comment: Cities are at database. I use their ids to get from database. There are some users related to cities. This is an example from written code and I will rewrite it in Java later. For now just I should change something to get work that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$citiesids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,22);

$currentUsers = array();
$addedUsers = array();

foreach ($citesids as $cityId) {
    $currentUsers[$cityId] = array();
    $addedUsers[$cityId] = array();
}
```

is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Use [foreach](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
$cities = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,22);
foreach ($cities as $cityId) {
    // use $cityId as before.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean exactly, but perhaps you mean using the array of cityIds instead of a simple counter?

In that case, simply use a foreach:

```
foreach ($cities as $cityId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to iterate over cities, but not all of them

```
$cityCount=22;
$cities = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,22);

for ($cityId = 1; $cityId <= $cityCount; $cityId++) {
  // only handle the cases that where cityid is in the cities-array   
  if (!in_array($cityId, $cities)) continue; 

  // do what you like here
}
```

Comment: @kamaci it's not helpful as it's ugly and durty. NEVER use it this way. Imagine your next city id will be 1562. It's shameful answer.

Comment: hey, i know it can be done smoother like the answer of Nowhereman or Sjoerd, but my solution works (i know it is not perfect in means of performance)

Answer (score -1):

```
$cityCount=10;
$currentUsers = array();
$addedUsers = array();
for ($cityId = 1; $cityId <= $cityCount; $cityId++) {
    $currentUsers[$cityId] = array();
    array_push($addedUsers,$cityId);


}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($addedUsers);
echo '</pre>';

array_push($addedUsers,22);//whatever city you want to added (22 for example)

echo '<pre>';
print_r($addedUsers);
echo '</pre>';
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
)

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 22 // just Added
)
```

Comment: this could be considered as a fun, not an answer.

Comment: So it should foreach ($cities as $cityId)  the answer,what exacly they want?

Answer (score -2):

As I suspected, it should be SQL query, not PHP code
Something like

```
select * from user WHERE where city IN (SELECT * FROM cities)
```

or whatever suits your **hidden and secret** needs

Comment: Firstly its not my code that I wrote I need to make small changes on it cos I gonna take it into another infrastructure soon. Secondly the system is a bit complex, that code is for updating the sessions of user but you are right it needs to change and I will.

Comment: You dont know how is the system and don't know the deploy system at office. If it would be so easy like that I could use that but city table doesnt hold just the cities for people that should be sesion updated. Also I dont want to change add any more database code for a system that need even milliseconds. I know what is your's, not to know anything about a system and think that you know everything.